# validate textarea depending on dropdown selection using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using JQuery Validation plugin (http://jqueryvalidation.org) to validate an html form. I would like the textarea field to be required only if the dropdown menu selection value is 0. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Here's what the form looks like:

```
<form name="reviewProduct" id="reviewProduct" method="POST">
    <select id="reaction" name="reaction">
    <option value="1">Yes. I like it.</option>
    <option value="0">No. I don't like it.</option>
    </select>
    <textarea id="explainwhy" name="explainwhy" rows="4"></textarea>
</form>

<script>    
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#reviewProduct').validate({
    rules: {
        explainwhy: {
            required: {
                depends: function () {
                    return $('#reaction').val() == "0";
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: You really should have made an attempt to solve this yourself before asking for help.

Comment: Hey Sparky. Every attempt was made.

Comment: See [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): _"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results**. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"_

Comment: You're correct Sparky. Any future posts will include my failed attempt. Thanks for being that to light for me.

Comment: To avoid potential down-votes, I suggest that you edit your OP. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `depends` method to make the `required` rule "depend" upon a set of conditions.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#reviewProduct').validate({
        rules: {
            explainwhy: {
                required: {
                    depends: function () {
                        return $('#reaction').val() == "0";
                    }
                }
            },
            reaction: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/SSA4Y/**